# Values for previous X rows based on time between rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, time

I have a simple table:

```
ID--- CreateDate --- Value 

1 --- 2015-09-25 10:00 --- 1 
1 --- 2015-09-25 10:30 --- 2 
1 --- 2015-09-25 11:00 --- 3 
1 --- 2015-09-25 11:30 --- 2 
1 --- 2015-09-25 12:00 --- 1 
2 --- 2015-09-25 10:00 --- 2 
2 --- 2015-09-25 10:30 --- 3 
2 --- 2015-09-25 11:00 --- 3 
2 --- 2015-09-25 11:30 --- 3 
2 --- 2015-09-25 12:00 --- 2
```

I need to find sequences in the data where the Value is above 2 for 1½ hours or more within a specific timeframe IE 24 hours. This wouldn't be a problem if I could be sure each measure point (row from each ID) came at exactly 30 minute intervals.

Then, using windowed functions, my result would look like

```
2 --- 2015-09-25 10:30 --- 3 
2 --- 2015-09-25 11:00 --- 3 
2 --- 2015-09-25 11:30 --- 3
```

The problem is - some IDs will generate twice as many rows (and some even more). Like this:

```
1 --- 2015-09-25 10:00 --- 1 
1 --- 2015-09-25 10:30 --- 3 
1 --- 2015-09-25 11:00 --- 3 
1 --- 2015-09-25 11:30 --- 3 
1 --- 2015-09-25 12:00 --- 1 
2 --- 2015-09-25 10:00 --- 1 
2 --- 2015-09-25 10:15 --- 2 
2 --- 2015-09-25 10:30 --- 3 
2 --- 2015-09-25 10:45 --- 3 
2 --- 2015-09-25 11:00 --- 3 
2 --- 2015-09-25 11:15 --- 3 
2 --- 2015-09-25 11:30 --- 3 
2 --- 2015-09-25 11:45 --- 2 
2 --- 2015-09-25 12:00 --- 2
```

In this case I'd want my result to look like this:

```
1 --- 2015-09-25 10:30 --- 3 
1 --- 2015-09-25 11:00 --- 3 
1 --- 2015-09-25 11:30 --- 3 
2 --- 2015-09-25 10:30 --- 3 
2 --- 2015-09-25 10:45 --- 3 
2 --- 2015-09-25 11:00 --- 3 
2 --- 2015-09-25 11:15 --- 3 
2 --- 2015-09-25 11:30 --- 3
```

But, to the best of my knowledge, windowed functions doesn't support time/column based arguments. So what are my alternatives when I cannot "count" on a specific amount of rows?

I am open to suggestions on alternatives to using SQL server, table structures, anything :)

Comment: Maybe I'm a little dumb, this morning, but I don't understand Your problem so I try to see if I've understood or not:
You need all records where Value is Above X and the date and time is Between Two Values? or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  You need to identify the groups with adjacent sequences with a value greater than 2.  One method is to use the difference of row numbers:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(value) over (partition by id, grp) as maxvalue,
             count(*) over (partition by id, grp) as cnt
      from (select t.*, 
                   (row_number() over (partition by id order by createdate) -
                    row_number() over (partition by id, (case when value > 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                                       order by createdate)
                   ) as grp
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t
where cnt >= 3 and maxvalue > 2
```

The query then calculates the number in each group and the value, choosing the ones with the larger values and sequences of at least 3 in length.  Note:  you could get the min and max times and check that the difference is at least 1.5 hours as well.  However, a sequence of length three seems to meet your conditions.